# How to change SQL server password in Magento?

Tags: password-recovery

I would like to change the password for my sql server but I got the access denied message from Magento once I changed the password. So how can I change the setting in Magento to reflect the password change? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In order ,to change **MySQL password of a Magento system**,you need go Magento main configuration file **`local.xml`** at  ***`yourMagentodir>app/etc/`***

**Open `local.xml` and here your find below setting**

```
<password><![CDATA[YOUR_DB_PASSWORD]]></password>
```

just change `YOUR_DB_PASSWORD to your password`

**Under** `CDATA[]` ,you need to put `password`

Comment: Thanks for your promt reply. I have amended the password in the local.xml file but still unable to access Magento. Here's what I got for my first line of error message: #0 /home/content/63/9549963/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(109): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()

Comment: I think you should clear the cache and recompile (if using compiler)

Comment: you may also have a look on this post https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_reset_admin_password_in_magento/

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue.Errors are showing

```
    Trace:
#0 /home2/cheredes/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(115): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
#1 /home2/cheredes/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1246): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; char...')
#2 /home2/cheredes/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(80): Mage_Core_Model_App->getResponse()
#3/home2/cheredes/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(202): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->getResponse()
#4 /home2/cheredes/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 /home2/cheredes/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#6 /home2/cheredes/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home2/cheredes/public_html/index.php(86): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

Comment: how to resolve this issue ?