# DB user and password

Tags: mysql, user, access, password-recovery

Hello everyone I'm a newbie. Can I recover somewhere the user and the password to access the MySQL database? I lost them and I think they are the always the same that I entered when first configuring the Magento installation. Is there a way to access that panel again? Or another solution? The website is hosted on an external server, I don't know if this has nothing to do with it.
Thanks a lot

Comment: ckd this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32366/how-to-change-sql-server-password-in-magento/32367#32367

Answer (score 2):

The credentials for the db are stored in `app/etc/local.xml`.  Look in there.